# Dual-boot OSx (El Capitan) and Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't work after updates

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, macosx, refind

I follow [this](https://youtu.be/IQIaDO9nR6Y) tutorial to install Ubuntu 16.04 along with my OSx. Initially, it worked. I could boot in both systems using the rEFInd interface. But after I installed updates and some software* on my Ubuntu it doesn't boot anymore.

When I turn on the computer it goes to rEFInd screen, which gives me the option to choose OSx and Ubuntu. Initially, I could click in any of them and they will boot.

Now, since I rebooted for the first time (after the updates) when I choose the Ubuntu option it starts the boot screen (purple screen with 'Ubuntu' and a sign of 'loading'), it never leaves that screen. I have waited a long time and nothing changes.

I tried to reinstall Ubuntu, but the same problem happened. Can I still fix it or should I try another Ubuntu version?

* I haven't changed any configuration files, I basically installed compilers, tools & libs.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please be more specific about "it doesn't boot anymore"? Does it just boot direcly into OS X, without the option to boot Ubuntu? Or when you turn on the computer, are you just stuck at a totally blank screen, or the rEFInd menu? If there is there text on the screen,  what does it say? It would be helpful if you could please edit your question to include this type of information. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that, I've edited my question.

Comment: In OS X, re-install rEFInd. When you reboot, there might or might not then be a new Ubuntu option. Select the one that references `vmlinuz-*`, hit F2 or Insert twice, use the resulting simple text editor to *remove* the `quiet splash` options (if they're present; they may not be), and hit Enter/Return to boot. This will result in a verbose boot that may provide more clues about what's going wrong. (Or maybe you'll get lucky and it'll boot completely.) Post details of error messages you see or the point where it hangs. (Take a photo of the screen and share it, if necessary.)